# Newbie Installation Issue: Oracle JDK7 on AWS/Tomcat

Tags: amazon-web-services, java

I'm trying to install JDK7 from the Oracle site on my nice new AWS server &

```
 sudo rpm -ivh ./jdk-7u7-linux-i586.rpm
```

produced

```
Unpacking JAR files...
        rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/rt.pack
        jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/jsse.pack
...etc...
```

As a bonus issue, attempts to reinstall using a newly downloaded .rpm file produce:

```
package jdk-2000:1.7.0_07-fcs.i586 is already installed
```

Which is very frustrating because clearly it's not... really... I think. (I could be wrong)
Thanks for any help you can offer...

Comment: For your bonus issue, try adding --force to the ``rpm`` invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the package could be corrupt. In a temporary directory, try this:

`rpm2cpio /path/to/jdk-7u7-linux-i586.rpm | cpio -vid`

and see if all files are successfully extracted. For your bonus issue, try adding --force to the `rpm` invocation?